# bad behavior of tr function while passing 2 arguments

Tags: shell, tr

I would like to change a parameter 1 by a parameter 2 but the output is not correct

```
 #!/bin/sh 
    getline="hello mr XXX";    
    name="NAME";
    echo $getline  | tr "XXX" "$name" ;
```

the output is :  "hello mr MMM"

do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` command maps character to character on a 1-to-1 basis i.e `X` in input is mapped to `M` in replacement (the last mapping).

to replace `XXX` with the value of variable `NAME` you can use `sed` or parameter substitution like this:

```
$ sed 's/XXX/'"$name"'/g' <<< "hello mr XXX"
hello mr NAME
```

OR

```
$ echo ${getline//XXX/$name}
hello mr NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` expects a 1:1 mapping between the input/ouput sets:

```
tr XXX NAME
   123 1234
```

Since you have THREE identical chars in the input, only the last one is used for the mapping, and X #3 maps to character #3 in the "replacements" parameter, which happens to be `M`

If you'd expand the command out a bit more:

```
$ echo hello mr XXXYZ|tr "XXXY" "NAME"
hello mr MMMEZ
```

`Y` maps to `E`, because they're both the 4th char in the in/out sets.